# How can i apply NLP in facebook bot using Flask framework?

Tags: python, flask, facebook-chatbot

I am done working with **echo** and **manual** response in facebook bot.

But I can't able to apply NLP. If I send message, I will get response automatically without setting manual response message.

Answer (score 0):

After successful echo operation of user message, you can integrate [Wit API](https://wit.ai/) to your Flask application. This will add NLP functionalities to your bot.

Here is a good short tutorial series of how to integrate **Wit API** to provide NLP services in messenger bot: [Facebook Messenger Bot Tutorial (using Python) | Wit.ai Integration (Part-1)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x2t9OqTb4kE&index=8&list=PLyb_C2HpOQSC4M3lzzrql7DSppTeAxh-x)

Finish the 8th, 9th and 10th tutorials and you will get some head start on this. Good luck!